# replace different values in column using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the character variable ID.  It has IDs with 9 digits and 3 other values: blank, N/A and NA.  I want to replace blank, N/A and NA with 999999999.

I tried using this:

```
df$id <- gsub('','999999999', df$id)
```

But it replaces all blanks (even with valid IDs).  What is the best way to do this?

```
id <- c("", "N/A", "123456789", "NA","123456789")
> dummydata <- data.frame(id)
```

Comment: " all blanks (even with valid IDs)" You mean it replaces only the blank? Or it replaces every value with blank?

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6103040).

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput`.  If the data is too long, you can provide a sample with `dput(head(df$id, 15))`

Comment: It replaces every blank space, so in a valid ID, it will have 999999999 ID 999999999.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(id = parse_number(id), id = coalesce(id, 999999999))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this reproducible example:

```
set.seed(100)
dt <- data.frame(id = sample(rep(c(1:10, c(NA, "N/A", " ", "")), 2)))
replace_value <- 999999999

dt$orig <- dt$id
dt$id                    <- gsub(" ", replace_value, dt$id)
dt$id                    <- gsub("N/A", replace_value, dt$id)
dt$id[is.na(dt$id)]      <- replace_value
dt$id[nchar(dt$id) == 0] <- replace_value
```

> ```
>           id    orig
> 1          2    2
> 2          8    8
> 3  999999999     
> 4         10   10
> 5          9    9
> 6          8    8
> 7  999999999     
> 8          5    5
> 9          4    4
> 10 999999999  N/A
> 11         4    4
> 12         3    3
> 13         6    6
> 14 999999999  N/A
> 15 999999999 <NA>
> 16 999999999     
> 17 999999999     
> 18         9    9
> 19         7    7
> 20        10   10
> 21         2    2
> 22         3    3
> 23 999999999 <NA>
> 24         1    1
> 25         5    5
> 26         6    6
> 27         1    1
> 28         7    7
> ```